# Como criar um Radio button com imagem?

Tags: jquery, html, css, radiobutton

Como posso fazer com que um *Radio Button* se transforme em uma Imagem?  Preciso fazer uma galeria de imagens dentro de um formulário para, ao clicarmos na imagem estaria selecionando um *radio button* como na imagem abaixo:

<kbd>[image: exemplo]</kbd>

Comment: Só podes selecionar uma imagem de cada vez como num radio button ou queres poder selecionar várias de cada vez?

Comment: Ola Sergio... sim uma de cada vez

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não precisas de jQuery ou JavaScript para isto. Usa `label` e CSS.

Cada elemento `input` pode ser associado a uma `label` que transmite ao `input` cliques. Se esconderes o `input` ficas com a funcionalidade que queres. **Nota:** para esconder o `input` tens de usar `visibility: hidden;` ou `opacity: 0;` pois se esconderes com `display: none;` ele não vai ser enviado via formulário.

Assim, tendo o input e o label lado a lado (e tem de ser assim para a lógica do CSS funcionar) podes ter algo deste género:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
        visibility: hidden;
}
    
label {
    display: block;
    border: 4px solid #666;
    width: 60px;
    float: left;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
    border-color: #ccf;
}
img {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="imagem" id="i1" />
<label for="i1"><img src="http://vkontakte.ru/images/gifts/256/81.jpg" alt=""></label>
<input type="radio" name="imagem" id="i2" />
<label for="i2"><img src="http://vkontakte.ru/images/gifts/256/82.jpg" alt=""></label>
<input type="radio" name="imagem" id="i3" />
<label for="i3"><img src="http://vkontakte.ru/images/gifts/256/83.jpg" alt=""></label>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0u1qqx6c/

Comment: Perfeito era isso mesmo, so que estou com um probleminha... o na pagina tem outros labels e esta recebendo o css dos radio bottons

Comment: @FabioHenrique isso é simples de resolver. Dá uma classe específica a esses elementos para os distinguir no CSS ou cria uma div para esses elementos assim: https://jsfiddle.net/0u1qqx6c/2/

Comment: Sergio esse script teria teria alguma outra forma de funcionar sem utilizando id=  do input pois ele conflitou com um js que tambem pega o id=

Comment: @FabioHenrique a minha solução não tem script, e isso é o melhor mesmo. Podes explicar melhor onde dá conflito? Também dá para fazer com JavaScript, mas prefiro ajudar-te a fazer com HTML.

Comment: to colocando aqui como esta o script  https://jsfiddle.net/fabioo7/by1nvtdh/

Comment: @FabioHenrique o que está a dar problema é esta linha -> `params += '&foto='+document.getElementById('foto[]').value;`?

Comment: sim...  E essA linha mesmo  como esse js tb pega o id  ai para de funcionar o css do radio,

Comment: @FabioHenrique nesse caso podes usar outro seletor. Curiosamente esse `input` devia ter atributo `value` certo? Testa assim: `params += '&foto='+document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked').value;`. Seria bom dares um `name` a esses campos... Nesse caso ainda ficava mais simples! Se mostrares o HTML todo (renderizado) posso ajudar-te a simplificar esse JavaScript.

Comment: Show funcionou... obrigado pela ajuda